# Creating component for forms in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a form in react, if I do this:

```
        <NameLabel>Name</NameLabel>
        <Name
          name="name"
          type="text"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          required
        />
```

and then:

```
const Name = styled.input`
  // some code
`

const NameLabel = styled.label`
  // some code
`
```

which works fine. I am not sure if this is good because if I add another input field, then I have to style it again with the same style used for the name input. Is there another option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use `<NameLabel>` and `<Name>` multiple times. You don't have to define it again for each control in the form. The problem I see here is the naming you have used for the components. I'd change them as below

```js
const StyledInput = styled.input`
  border: 1px solid red;
`

const StyledLabel = styled.label`
  font-size: 12px;
`
```

then use them like

```js
<StyledLabel>Name</StyledLabel>
<StyledInput
 name="name"
 type="text"
 value={this.state.name}
 onChange={this.handleInputChange}
 required
/>

<StyledLabel>Email</StyledLabel>
<StyledInput
 name="email"
 type="email"
 value={this.state.email}
 onChange={this.handleInputChange}
 required
/>
```